# Is it possible to group geoJSON objects/polygons in a layer?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, layers

In the leaflet.js documentation an example with layers of markers is documented. I would like to create a layer of polygons in GeoJSON format. Is this possible?

I've defined a variable for each GeoJSON polygon, called route1, route2 etc. My .js file looks like this:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [55.676098, 12.568337],
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

//============
//Create layer
//============

var Southroutes = new L.layerGroup([route1, route2, route3, route4, route5]);

L.geoJSON(Southroutes).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#geojson), you will see that a GeoJSON layer in Leaflet extends FeatureGroup (which in turn extends LayerGroup).  In other words, it is already a LayerGroup.   In practice this works by all features in a GeoJson object being grouped and you don't need to separately bundle them in a new L.layerGroup (the L.geoJSON is sufficient if they are all in the same GeoJson dataset).  See the examples [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).  In these examples you will see how multiple GeoJson features can be in one 'layer' (because it is a LayerGroup).

You could also use your attribute to render the routes differently as per the emaples linked earlier.

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
var route1Layer = L.geoJSON(route1);
var route2Layer = L.geoJSON(route2);
var route3Layer = L.geoJSON(route3);
var route4Layer = L.geoJSON(route4);
var route5Layer = L.geoJSON(route5);

group = new L.FeatureGroup();
group.addLayer(route1Layer);
group.addLayer(route2Layer);
group.addLayer(route3Layer);
group.addLayer(route4Layer);
group.addLayer(route5Layer);
map.addLayer(group);
```

What I ultimately wanted was to assign features to the group. For example color all the routes red:

```
group.setStyle(
    function(feature){
        return {color: 'red'};
    }
);
```

And it did the job.